# Get props from template ref

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Is it possible to get the properties of a vue component by a template ref?
I could use `defineExpose` but i am interested if there is another solution.
I am using vue 3 composition api.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const childRef = ref()

const foo = () => {
  console.log(childRef.value.someData)
}
</script>

<template>
  <Child ref="childRef" some-data="my special data" />
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

Comment: The correct way is defineExpose. You can access internal instance childRef.value.proxy but this shouldn't be done under normal circumstances

Comment: If this is the correct way please add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding another answer using `defineExpose` API.

First, you need to expose the properties of the child component which you would like to access in the parent component via the `ref` method.

In your case, as you want to access the props of the child component then you need to expose the props using the `defineExpose` API.

`Child.vue`

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineExpose } from "vue";
  
const props = defineProps({
  someData: String
})

defineExpose({
  props,
})
</script>

<template>
  {{ someData }}
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

`parent.vue`

```
<template>
  <Child ref="childRef" some-data="my special data" /><br><br>
  <v-btn @click="foo">Access Child Component Properties</v-btn>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Child from './Child.vue'

const childRef = ref()

const foo = () => {
  console.log(childRef.value?.props?.someData)
}
</script>
```

Here is a [working demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the `defineComponent` API and bind the `childRef` template ref to the Child component using the ref attribute. For example-

```
const childRef = ref<typeof Child>()
```

We also need to import the Child component using the `defineComponent` function so we can access it in the components option.

`parent.vue`

```
<template>
  <Child ref="childRef" some-data="my special data" /><br><br>
  <v-btn @click="foo">Access Child Component Properties</v-btn>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, defineComponent } from 'vue'
import Child from './Child.vue'

const childRef = ref<typeof Child>()

const foo = () => {
  console.log(childRef.value?.someData)
}
  
defineComponent({
  components: {
    Child,
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      childRef,
      foo
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

`child.vue`

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
  someData: String
})
</script>

<template>
  {{ someData }}
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

Here is a [working demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

Comment: The OP likely uses script setup syntax, and defineComponent is unnecessary. I suppose the problem is that this way all properties that aren't explicitly defined with defineExpose are considered private

Comment: Hey, @EstusFlask Got it. I thought as OP mentioned that he already knows about defineExpose then there could be another way using defineComponent.

Comment: Maybe add a new answer then if defineExpose is the correct solution. I want to use best practice stuff :). @NehaSoni

Comment: Hey, @MrSpt. Added the answer with defineExpose API. Now, you can use as per our requirements.